# WinUI 3: Datagrid is always null if it is in a basis page

Tags: winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

My goal is to have a basic page with a data grid and generic functions in the background. I now want to create a page that inherits from the base page.
The datagrid is from the Windows Community Toolkit.
Unfortunately, the data grid is then not initilized. When I create an instance of the base page it is again initialized.

BasePage.xaml:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="SHS.WinUI.Views.BasePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SHS.WinUI.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Margin="10">
</Page>
```

BasePage.cs:

```cs
public abstract partial class BasePage : Page
{   
    private BaseViewModel _ViewModel;
    public BaseViewModel BaseViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _ViewModel;
        }
        set { _ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public abstract void SetViewModel();


    public BasePage() : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }    
}
```

MasterDataEditPage xaml:

```xml
<views:BasePage
    xmlns:views="using:SHS.WinUI.Views"
    x:Class="SHS.WinUI.Views.MasterData.MasterDataEditPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SHS.WinUI.Views.MasterData"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CommandBar Background="Transparent" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Hinzufügen" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Löschen" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Speichern" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        </CommandBar>
        <controls:DataGrid
            x:Name="myDataGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Grid.Row="1"           
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" Color="Transparent" />
            </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
            
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</views:BasePage>
```

MasterDataEditPage.cs:

```cs
public partial class MasterDataEditPage : BasePage
{
    public MasterDataEditPage() : base()
    {        
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetViewModel<T>(T viewModel) where T : IMasterDataEditViewModel
    {
        viewModel.SetDataGrid(myDataGrid);
        viewModel.InitDataGridColumns();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    public override void SetViewModel()
    {
        // Not Implemented
    }
}
```

ClerkMasterDataPage xaml:

```xml
<local:MasterDataEditPage
    x:Class="SHS.WinUI.Views.MasterData.ClerkMasterDataPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SHS.WinUI.Views.MasterData"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
</local:MasterDataEditPage>
```

ClerkMasterDataPage.cs:

```cs
public sealed partial class ClerkMasterDataPage : MasterDataEditPage
{
    public MasterDataEditViewModel<Clerk, Sachbearbeiter> ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public ClerkMasterDataPage() : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In codebehind of MasterDataEditPage I access the datagrid "myDataGrid", which is always null. Am I doing this completely wrong or is there a better alternative?

MasterDataEditViewModel.cs:

```cs
public partial class MasterDataEditViewModel<ModelType, DatabaseType> : BaseViewModel, INavigationAware, 
    IMasterDataEditViewModel
{
    private readonly List<DataGridSelectionType> _dataGridSelectionTypes;
    private readonly IMasterDataService<DatabaseType> _masterDataRepository;
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly string _controllerName;
    private DataGrid _dataGrid;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ModelType _SelectedItem;

    private bool CanDelete => SelectedItem != null;

    public ObservableCollection<ModelType> Source { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ModelType>();

    public MasterDataEditViewModel(string name,
                                   Symbol symbol,
                                   List<DataGridSelectionType> dataGridSelectionTypes,
                                   IMasterDataService<DatabaseType> masterDataRepository,
                                   IMessageService messageService,
                                   IMapper mapper,
                                   string controllerName) : base(name, symbol)
    {
        this._dataGridSelectionTypes = dataGridSelectionTypes;
        _masterDataRepository = masterDataRepository;
        this._messageService = messageService;
        this._mapper = mapper;
        this._controllerName = controllerName;
    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter)
    {
        Source.Clear();

        var data = await _masterDataRepository.GetAll(_controllerName);

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Source.Add(_mapper.Map<ModelType>(item));
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom()
    {
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Add()
    {
        var newItem = Activator.CreateInstance<ModelType>();
        Source.Add(newItem);
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanDelete))]
    private async Task Delete()
    {
        if(SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var result = await _messageService.ShowYesNoAsync("Frage", "Möchten sie wirklich löschen?");
            if(result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            {
                await _masterDataRepository.Delete(_mapper.Map<DatabaseType>(SelectedItem), _controllerName);
                Source.Remove(SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private Task Save()
    {
        return _masterDataRepository.UpdateAll(_mapper.Map<List<DatabaseType>>(Source), _controllerName);
    }

    public void SetDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        _dataGrid = dataGrid;
    }

    public void InitDataGridColumns()    
    {
        foreach (var item in _dataGridSelectionTypes)
        {
            switch (item.DataGridType)
            {
                case Enums.DataGridType.DataGridText:
                    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new();
                    textColumn.Header = item.HeaderName;
                    textColumn.Binding = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding() { Path = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath(item.BindingName) };
                    _dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
                    break;
                case Enums.DataGridType.DataGridCheckBox:
                    DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkboxColumn = new();
                    checkboxColumn.Header = item.HeaderName;
                    checkboxColumn.Binding = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding() { Path = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath(item.BindingName) };
                    _dataGrid.Columns.Add(checkboxColumn);
                    break;
                case Enums.DataGridType.DataGridCombobox:
                    break;
                case Enums.DataGridType.NotVisible:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post more related code so one can reproduce your problem and see how to fix it. In this case, code round the page inheritance, the Source property for the DataGrid at least. If you also post what you are trying to achieve with this inheritance, maybe I (or someone else) can give a better way to do it. Usually, inheriting from a Page wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I hope the updated question is more understandable now.

Comment: Could you please show more information about Source in `ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" `

Comment: I updated my question and added the viewmodel "MasterDataEditViewModel.cs" at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that you should reconsider your implementation. First of all, generally, ViewModels shouldn't know about the UI. So, you shouldn't pass the ``DataGrid`` to the ViewModel. You should use bindings to fill the ``DataGrid``. Secondly, I still can't see why you want to use inheritance on ``Pages``. If they look the same, you should use the same ``Page`` and bind different data to it. Or create different ``Pages`` and implement them to have the same (or closer) look.

Comment: Forgot to add that, if you need to setup the ``DataGrid``, columns for example, you can do it in code-behind.

Comment: As @AndrewKeepCoding said, if you need to use like this, you can define Source in code behind, without ViewModels.

Comment: I need a Viewmodel cause if created the App with Templates Studio. The navigationview creates the Page via viewmodel

Comment: So, you want to 1) Do navigation on a Template Studio generated app?, 2) Navigate among at least 2 pages (MasterDataEditPage and ClerkMasterDataPage)?, 3) Both pages has the same look and same data structure to show?, 3) Both pages has different data to show? or the same data but only MasterDataEditPage can edit the data?

Comment: Yes, in MasterDataEditPage are the Ui controls and functions to initial the generic Viewmodel. In ClerkMastereditpage i define the columns and the generic Data to use. ClerkMasterEditPage doesn't define any ui Elements, Just inherits from MasterDataEdit Page, so i dont have to define the Datagrid several Times. For the navigationview i registered the generic Viewmodel with the ClerkMasterEditPage , so i can call the Page via viewmodel in NavigationView

Comment: I took a look at the Template Studio but in the way navigation is implemented, still I would say that you should have 2 individual pages for master and clerk. After all it's just 2 pages (or a bit more maybe) but it's easy and clear that way. Sorry.